How we can notify mobile app about messages (Django/React Native)?
What is the best implementation of notifications (about messages, new posts) to the client, Websockets, push notifications, or webhooks? The project consists of a server part in Django and React Native on the client.
WebSockets, WebHooks, PUSH

You can’t send Push Notification direct to the mobile device.
You have to use APNS for iOS or GCM for android or FCM for cross Platform messaging.
There is an python implementation for FCM.

Thanks for answering, i'll analyze info about fsm, but also i'm looking for another realizations with sockets or something else, that no need 3rd party services.

AFAIK that's not possible, due to power saving there is only one service on a OS which is running all the time to process incoming notifications.
Imagine hundreds of installed apps would start an own daemon, that would drain the battery ...
